# AMD Ryzen 4700U Processor and AMD Radeon Graphics Machine Failing to Resume After Suspend on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: suspend

I've recently switched over to Ubuntu 22.10 as the main OS for my machine but I've been frustrated by an issue with suspending my machine. Whenever I close the lid to my laptop or suspend via command line and try to resume, my machine fails to turn back on and I'm left staring at a black screen. My keyboard still lights up and everything so I'm pretty confused as to what could be the root of my problems. I went ahead and dumped the `demsg` logs and after some digging it seems like the issue is something to do with my AMD GPU driver, but I'm a linux newbie so I would appreicate any guidance in diagnosing my problem.
[Here](https://0x0.st/HK5s.log) is a link to the full log. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yes. My crystal ball broke. So could you state your hardware? You describe a classic driver problem. It occurs with NVIDIA and AMD, only seldom with intel. `inxi -G` or `lspci -v | grep VGA` should do. **Copy the output of those commands into your question**

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/j517jj/amd_ryzen_7_4700u_suspendhibernate_not_working_on/ claims it works on kernel 5.13. what brand machine? the link states "ThinkPads have a setting that is "Windows" (disable S3) or "Linux" (enables S3)"  that could be it too.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your comments. This turned out to be a bug with the Linux kernel version I was using, I upgraded to 6.2.0 and I no longer see this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).